# How to tell if a thread is deadlocked or just sleeping in ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, deadlock

Im working on a script that monitors ruby threads. Given the following code:

```
thread_1 = Thread.new { Thread.stop }
thread_2 = Thread.new { sleep(0.5) }

sleep(0.1)
puts "Thread 1 Status: #{thread_1.status}"
puts "Thread 2 Status: #{thread_2.status}"

thread_1.join
thread_2.join
```

How can I tell that `thread_1` is actually deadlocked while thread_2 is just sleeping before calling `join` on them?

Both statuses say `sleep`

```
Thread 1 Status: sleep
Thread 2 Status: sleep
test.rb:8:in `join': No live threads left. Deadlock? (fatal)
    from test.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]

Thanks!